# CSS line-height property larger than font-size property

Tags: html, styles, css, text-size

I am having a very annoying issue where I want to align the top of an image with text but the letters are actually slightly below the line height.

I created simple sample with a classic movie to illustrate the issue below.

HTML:

```
<img src="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w92/wcI3VMHw2TqtPVIkS4wpmxBJzWB.jpg" />
<p>Big</p>
<p>Admin</p>
```

CSS:

```
p, h4{
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1em;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

img{
    float:left;
    width:46px;
}
```

Output (in Chrome):

[image]

As you can see while the line height is aligned with the top of the image, the text itself isn't. I have tried all vertical-align options with no fix.

Why is line height larger than font size even when they are both set to equal dimensions?
How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has more to do with typography in general than CSS. There are a number of vertical guides that factor into font design. I assume you want the [cap height](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_height) to match the top of the image.

I added your example to jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ahXpH/1/ and replicated it. If you zoom in, you can see that the "i" in "Big" is actually taller than the B, while the "g" extends beyond the confines of the paragraph itself. Inspecting the element in Chrome reveals that the `line-height` and `font-size` match.

To get around this, you'll have to adjust the `margin-top` and visually line it up. For my jsfiddle version, this happens to be `margin-top: -8px;` with `font-family: "Trebuchet MS"` and `font-size:48px`. ( http://jsfiddle.net/ahXpH/4/ ) However, if you remove "Trebuchet MS" and use your fallback front of Arial, you'll see that it no longer lines up and is a pixel above the image now.

Ultimately, I'm not sure if there is a pure CSS solution to this. Hardcoding the value will only work with one font, and may even differ from browser to browser.

Comment: That's a real shame, seems like a very simple and common requirement, I guess that's why we still have flash :) Negative margin values will work I guess but what happens when you zoom in? Will have to experiment to the what's the best solution, maybe using negative em's will work.

Comment: Choosing a common font will help, and SVG font rendering may provide more control, but that limits cross browser compatibility. It may be easiest to change your design instead.

Comment: Can't really change the design, but it doesn't have to be absolutely perfect so negative margin method should work ok.

Comment: Uppercase letters stay a little below the top of the font height. If “E” extended up to the top, what would happen to “Ê” for example? Note that not even all uppercase letters are equally tall; i.e., in Trebuchet MS, “B” is taller than “T”. So you would need to fine-tune the presentation so that a particular character, probably the initial letter of the text, is placed the way you prefer. As this varies by font, this would call for a downloadable font (web font, `@font-face`).

Comment: "what would happen to “Ê” for example?" - What we want is a simple way to tell the browser "take the top-most point of the current text and align it with <this>", so your point is misunderstanding the question.  I do appreciate your notes though, they are helpful in understanding the nature of the problem.